# Is the DriverManager class a Singleton in Java?

Tags: java, singleton

From [this](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-does-classforname-method-do/17) source I read that:

> You may have experience working with JDBC Drivers. For example, the
>   classloader attempts to load and link the Driver class in the
>   "org.gjt.mm.mysql" package. If successful, the static initializer is
>   called.

```
Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"); 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"myLogin", "myPassword");
```

> Let's see why you need Class.forName() to load a driver into memory. All JDBC
>   Drivers have a static block that registers itself with DriverManager
>   and DriverManager has static an initializer only.
>
> The MySQL JDBC Driver has a static initializer looks like this:

```
 static {
     try {
         java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
     } catch (SQLException E) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
     } }
```

Does this mean that DriverManager is a Singleton class?

Comment: Why do you think it might be a Singleton?

Comment: Well because I am registering a class type to some class, then when I wall a stati method from the Class I registered to, it is used? There is no instance of it. It is all static.

Comment: `static != singleton`.

Comment: There are no static classes in Java?

Comment: Actually, no, there aren't, unless you're talking about nested classes.  But that has nothing to do with this discussion.  To find out what a Singleton Java class might look like, see here: http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/designpatterns/

Comment: Your comment made me think you were implying it was a Static Class?

Comment: You said "it is all static."

Comment: I meant, the methods I am calling are static, my question is about the Class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a singleton. It's a pure utility class, with only static methods. There is 0 instance of this class. A singleton would have one instance of the class, and you would have access to this instance to call instance methods on it.

Java is documented, and it's open-source. You can look at the source of the class to understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks, I have never heard of a Utility Class. If there is no instance of it, how is the driver registered?

Comment: The class maintains its state in static variables.

Comment: @KorayTugay It has `static` state. (Global variables, -ish.)

Comment: Searching for utility class brings up the almost [exact same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_class) example.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Thanks, but the other way around did not work when I was searching for the DriverManager.

Comment: @JBNizet My initial thought was, every static method could call that single instance perhaps. I guess I understand it, thanks.

Comment: @MiserableVariable I was not find any information related to this question in the link you provided. It is a Utiliy class, but no other classes are registered to it.

Comment: Sorry my bad; the example on wiki does not have a static initializer